# Command line - How to launch "make all" in the parent directory?

Tags: linux, compilation, command, line

For exemple, I have folders like that : folder1/folder2.
I'm currently in the folder2, but I want to launch the command "make all" in the folder1 without moving in it.
How Can I do it?

Comment: Look at `make -C` option.

Comment: Working like a charm, thanks !